# Invalid identifier in pivot table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table

Here is my query:

```
SELECT NVL(REVENUE,0), OUTNO, MONTH_NAME FROM 
        (                                                            
         SELECT ROUND((RETURNDATE-STARTDATE)*DAILYRATE) AS REVENUE, 
                OUTNO, 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM RETURNDATE)AS MONTH_NAME
         FROM   RAGREEMENT LEFT JOIN VEHICLE ON 
                RAGREEMENT.LICENSENO=VEHICLE.LICENSENO
                AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM RETURNDATE)=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1
        )
PIVOT (
   SUM(REVENUE)
   FOR OUTNO IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,-1 AS TOTAL)
  )
ORDER BY MONTH_NAME;
```

and here is the error

```
SELECT NVL(REVENUE,0), OUTNO, MONTH_NAME FROM
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "OUTNO": invalid identifier
```

I fail to understand why this happens when SELECT *  works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did try doing it in the subquery, it has no effect on the final result. I still get NULL values

Answer (score 1):

What comes out from a pivot is a whole new set of columns names, and for each one of those new columns, you will need an `NVL()` or `COALESCE()`. This is because a completely new "matrix" is formed and many positions in this can be null. You cannot overcome this by using `NVL()` in the inner subquery.

Assuming you want months as columns your query might look more like this:

```
SELECT
   OUTNO
 , NVL('M1', 0)
 , NVL('M2', 0)
 , NVL('M3', 0)
 , NVL('M4', 0)
 , NVL('M5', 0)
 , NVL('M6', 0)
 , NVL('M7', 0)
 , NVL('M8', 0)
 , NVL('M9', 0)
 , NVL('M10', 0)
 , NVL('M11', 0)
 , NVL('M12', 0)
FROM (
     SELECT
            ROUND((RETURNDATE - STARTDATE) * DAILYRATE) AS REVENUE
          , OUTNO
          , 'M' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM RETURNDATE) AS MONTH_NAME
     FROM RAGREEMENT
     LEFT JOIN VEHICLE ON RAGREEMENT.LICENSENO = VEHICLE.LICENSENO
         AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM RETURNDATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 1
     )
PIVOT(
      SUM(REVENUE)
      FOR MONTH_NAME IN ('M1','M2','M3','M4','M5','M6','M7','M8','M9','M10','M11','M12')
     )
ORDER BY OUTNO;
```

This line produces the new columns:

```
      FOR MONTH_NAME IN ('M1','M2','M3','M4','M5','M6','M7','M8','M9','M10','M11','M12')
```

and it is each one of these you will need to "fix" for nulls in the select clause.

To put OUTNO values into columns requires a similar pattern but you need to know what the distinct set of values will be from that originating column. This MIGHT be 1,2,3,4,5,6,-1 but I wasn't certain.

nb: I prefixed 'M' in columns headings as many systems object to numbers as heading names.